# Checking if 2 (or more) EditTexts are empty

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, listener

Have 2 EditTexts (***accName*** and ***accMoney***) to be checked not to be empty in order to enable Button (***btnCrAcc***).

Tried to do like the code below. But it's actually not checking the way I'd like to. When I change the accMoney field, it's checking both EditTexts (but after that I can change accName to "" and the Button will be enabled anyway.

I think that one possible solution is to set the `addTextChangedListener` for both 2 fields, but it'll consume more memory?   (*Tell me: is that a good option*?)

Or I'd be really grateful if someone tells me how to do that correctly

I have this code:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         //..
         accName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        accMoney = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMoney);
         accDescr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDescr);
         accsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
         //..
        final Button btnCrAcc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateAccount);

    accMoney.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            btnCrAcc.setEnabled(!accName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty());
            btnCrAcc.setEnabled(!accMoney.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()); // check this
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Create a class implmenting TextWatcher:

```
  private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
             // check for both edittexts if any of them is empty than disable the button
             btnCrAcc.setEnabled(!accName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !accMoney.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
   }
```

> Than use that textwatcher for both edittexts:

```
MyTextWatcher myTextWatcher = new MyTextWatcher();

accName.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
accMoney.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            btnCrAcc.setEnabled(!accName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !accMoney.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    };

accMoney.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
accName.addTextChangedListener(watcher;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(accName.getText().length() == 0 || accMoney.getText().length() == 0) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single `TextWatcher` instance:

```
TextWatcher myWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override 
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    } 

    @Override 
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        btnCrAcc.setEnabled(!accName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && 
                            !accMoney.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty());
    } 
});

accName.addTextChangedListener(myWatcher);
accMoney.addTextChangedListener(myWatcher);
```